# DatetimeOffset and Sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm trying to implement a Data Access Layer against a Sqlite database. One of my tables contains a datetime field.

I have a problem in inserting data into this datetime field.

```
cmd.CommandText = string.Format(
                        "INSERT INTO Orders(" +
                            "OrderId, " +
                            "Status, " +
                            "CreationTime, " +
                            "LastModification, " +
                            "CreatorName) " +
                        "VALUES(@orderId,@status,@creation,@modification,@creator)";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderId", orderId);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", status);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@creation", creationTime);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@modification", lastModificationTime);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@creator", creatorName);
```

My table creation:

```
cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Orders(" +
                                  "OrderId TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, " +
                                  "Status TEXT, " +
                                  "CreationTime DATETIME, " +
                                  "LastModification DATETIME, " +
                                  "CreatorName TEXT)";
```

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking here. Please edit your question and give a statement surrounding what your expectation is.

Comment: Better to avoid conversions entirely and pass the values as parameters. Much safer and faster

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos of course it's much safer, but how it's faster

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of creating a string by hand, use a parameterized query and add the parameter values. Using String.Format will definitely cause conversion errors, as you found out, and expose you to SQL injection attacks.

When you use parameters the values are passed without any conversions so you never have to worry about either conversion errors or injection attacks. Most databases are also better able to optimize queries when they know which parts can change and which remain the same from one execution to the next.

In your case, you can use something like this:

```
cmd.CommandText= "INSERT INTO Orders(" +
                        "OrderId, " +
                        "Status, " +
                        "CreationTime, " +
                        "LastModification, " +
                        "CreatorName) " +
                    "VALUES (@orderId,@status,@creation,@modification,@creator)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderId",orderId);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status",status);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@creation",creation);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@modification",modification);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@creator",creator);
```

**Off topic - why parameterized queries are faster**

All servers have to parse queries to understand their structure and create an execution plan to run the query. The plan contains the indexes to use, the strategies for filtering or joining, temporary structures that may be needed etc. Creating this plan is expensive, so most servers cache the plans they create for later use.

Unless the server knows which values in your query are actually parameters and which hand-coded, it can't decide whether it can use an existing plan or create a new, without actually parsing the query. By specifying the parameters yourself you allow the server to create much better and reusable plans. This can be a significant boost if you execute a lot of queries every second.

Not to mention that passing values in their native form is much lighter and therefore faster than passing them as text.

Comment: Do I have to call **cmd.Parameters.Clear();** if I reuse the cmd.

Comment: DON'T reuse the command. Creating a command is cheap, why do you want to `reuse` it?

Comment: Where's your code? Assuming the database does exist, how did you creat the command? Did you open the connection before executing?

Comment: I have updated it again with the new insert code. I use a new command for each operation.